# How to display data monthly base in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query:

```
declare @startdate datetime='1/1/2012', @endate datetime='12/31/2012'
select * from hours1
where date_start between @startdate and @enddate
```

I want to show data like:

```
Jan
feb
March
...
December
```

could please help me how to get this?

Comment: So, you want to abbreviate January and February... but not March and December... what about the other months?

Comment: So you're wanting to group by the month, what do you want to show other than the month name? Are you wanting to sum up a column or get a count of rows?

Comment: Yes I want to show data group by month name with Year. I am taking doing sum(hours) so I wan to show hours used every month.

Comment: @SQlearner: Why don't you show exactly how you want the data for some of the months, describe what each column should be (month-name, sum of ..., etc) and indicate the relevant columns of your table. That way people can actually answer a question instead of guessing what you want to do.

Comment: can you give us an example of the table "hours1"?

Comment: ...we need more information than this!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to display the months between start and end date.

```
declare @startdate datetime='1/1/2012', 
        @endate datetime='12/31/2012'

SELECT
    DATENAME(month, date_start) 
FROM
    hours1
WHERE
    date_start between @startdate and @enddate
GROUP BY 
    DATENAME(month, date_start), 
    DATEPART(month, date_start)
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(month, date_start)
```

Comment: :but I want the group by depends on the startdate and enddate If startdate is 3/1/2013 and endddate is '6/30/2012' so It should show data like: March April May June...If am using your logic it shows only January

Comment: Perhaps you don't have any data for those months. (And it might show January if `end_date` is not on the same year as `start_date`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to aggregate data on a monthly basis, use the date functions:

```
select count(<count_grouped_items), sum(<sum_of_grouped_items>), ...

from hours1 
where date_start between @startdate and @enddate 
group by YEAR(date_start), MONTH(date_start) 
order by YEAR(date_start) asc, MONTH(date_starts) asc
```

Comment: :but I want the group by depends on the startdate and enddate If startdate is 3/1/2013 and endddate is '6/30/2012' so It should show data like: March April May June...If am using your logic it shows only January –

Comment: Above you wrote "declare startdate datetime='1/1/2012', endate datetime='12/31/2012'" so it groups every month in 2012. I assume that "date_start" is a field name in your table containing a date in each row, as long as you did'not define which fields your table actually contains else, my query above is not complete, it only shows how you can group by MONTHS. As Magnus already mentioned, you can retrieve the name of the month by DATENAME